# Can I place 'as' in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-usage

> Rich dad went on to say, "You should treat all debt, good or bad, the
>   same way you treat a loaded gun—with a lot of respect."

For the above sentence, can I place ***'as'*** after ***'way'*** then the sentence will go like this:***Rich dad went on to say, "You should treat all debt, good or bad, the same way as you treat a loaded gun—with a lot of respect."***

***My questions:*** For this sentence, I think my confusion comes from the usage of 'the same .....as....' and 'the same....that', but I'm can't find a very clear answer from google. Can anyone could explain this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The omission of words which are nevertheless understood to be in a clause is called _ellipsis._ Here, either _as_ or _that_ is omitted after _way_ and can be inserted without changing the meaning. This looks to me like a form of ellipsis. This exact question is discussed at [**this link**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211166/the-correct-form-of-the-same-way-the-same-way-as), but for some reason ellipsis isn't mentioned! (Google, by the way, is just a collection of things people have written: some correct, some incorrect, and many meaningless; it's not a very good teacher.)

Comment: So, when as and that followed by a clause, they can be interchangeable. Is that right?

Comment: Not in every case, but in most. The only rule in English is: **To every rule there is an exception.**

Comment: Can you explain what is the most situation?

Answer (score 1):

For your hypothetical advice,

> treat *it* the same way you treat

the equivalents are

> treat *it* the same way *as* you treat
>   treat *it* the same way *as* you *would* treat
>   treat *it* the same *as* you treat

the meanings are the same for all four, the differences are stylistic.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think you've understood my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can place "as" immediately after "way" and it would make perfect sense. Both versions of these sentences are perfectly fine. One thing I would change is the beginning. Instead of "Rich dad" it should be either:

- "Rich Dad went ..." or,
- "The rich dad went ..."

The first bullet point has "Dad" as a name (and proper noun). This is what the son calls his father. The second bullet point has "dad" as a common noun, and we put "the" before it. However, since we are describing the dad as rich, we put that descriptive adjective in between "the" and "dad": "the rich dad."